# PINE v5 - Plotting conditionally

Tags: pine-script

I'm unable to plot conditionally on Pine v5 when there is a 'na' value.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Discontinuous plots v5", "", true)

atr = ta.atr(7)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 100), ta.sma(close, 200))

long_stop_level = float(na)
long_profit_level = float(na)

long_stop_level := longCondition ? low - atr : long_stop_level[1]
long_profit_level := longCondition ? close + atr : long_profit_level[1]

if (longCondition)

    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Long Entry", stop= low - atr, limit= close + atr)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 100), ta.sma(close, 200))

short_stop_level = float(na)
short_profit_level = float(na)

short_stop_level := shortCondition ? high + atr : short_stop_level[1]
short_profit_level := shortCondition ? close - atr : short_profit_level[1]

if (shortCondition)

    strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Short Entry", stop= high + atr, limit= close - atr)

plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : long_stop_level, color=color.new(#FF0000, 70), linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : long_profit_level, color=color.new(#008000, 70), linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : short_stop_level, color=color.new(#FF0000, 70), linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : short_profit_level, color=color.new(#008000, 70), linewidth=2)
```

Same code structure converted to v3 works like a charm, as follows:

```
//@version=3
strategy("Discontinuous plots", "", true)

atr = atr(7)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 100), sma(close, 200))

long_stop_level = na
long_profit_level = na

long_stop_level := longCondition ? low - atr : long_stop_level[1]
long_profit_level := longCondition ? close + atr : long_profit_level[1]

if (longCondition)

    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Long Entry", stop= low - atr, limit= close + atr)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 100), sma(close, 200))

short_stop_level = na
short_profit_level = na

short_stop_level := shortCondition ? high + atr : short_stop_level[1]
short_profit_level := shortCondition ? close - atr : short_profit_level[1]

if (shortCondition)

    strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("TP/SL", "Short Entry", stop= high + atr, limit= close - atr)

plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : long_stop_level, color=red, style=linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : long_profit_level, color=green, style=linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : short_stop_level, color=red, style=linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : short_profit_level, color=green, style=linebr, linewidth=2)
```

I heard that an extension to the argument list to plot()'s display parameter is planned, but I could not find any workaround.

Is there a workaround available?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect and what you have at the moment. Can you attach a screenshot of your complete chart and show us what is going on?

Comment: This is what we have on [v3](https://www.tradingview.com/x/KiauYp2k/) and works as expected (plotted lines only when position != 0).

Comment: On the other hand, [v5](https://www.tradingview.com/x/TxHyFPk0/) shows plots on 'na' that should be omitted. Note that I'm using the same code structure (I just converted the v5 to v3)

Comment: Your script in that link is not exactly the same with what you have in your question because I can see that you have some inputs there. I don't have the problem you stated when I add the code in the question to my chart. Try adding `style=plot.style_linebr` to your plots in v5.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5

strategy('Discontinuous plots v5', '', true)

atr = ta.atr(7)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 100), ta.sma(close, 200))

long_stop_level = float(na)
long_profit_level = float(na)

long_stop_level := longCondition ? low - atr : long_stop_level[1]
long_profit_level := longCondition ? close + atr : long_profit_level[1]

if longCondition

    strategy.entry('Long Entry', strategy.long)
    strategy.exit('TP/SL', 'Long Entry', stop=low - atr, limit=close + atr)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 100), ta.sma(close, 200))

short_stop_level = float(na)
short_profit_level = float(na)

short_stop_level := shortCondition ? high + atr : short_stop_level[1]
short_profit_level := shortCondition ? close - atr : short_profit_level[1]

if shortCondition

    strategy.entry('Short Entry', strategy.short)
    strategy.exit('TP/SL', 'Short Entry', stop=high + atr, limit=close - atr)

plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : long_stop_level, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size <= 0 ? na : long_profit_level, color=color.new(color.green, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : short_stop_level, color=color.new(color.red, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
plot(strategy.position_size >= 0 ? na : short_profit_level, color=color.new(color.green, 0), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2)
```